# Not able to show Dialog box in Non Activity, RecyclerView Adapter Class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-context, android-dialog

I am using `Recyclerview` in my `Fragment`.I have `Adapter` class for my RecyclerView.I need to show `AlertDialog` in one method which I have written in `AdapterClass`. But I am getting an error as

> android.app.Activity cannot be applied to android.content.Context.

This is the code for my `AlertClass`

```
public class AlertClass {

        public void noInternetAlert(Activity activity)
        {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
            builder.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access this.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
}
```

This is code for my method in `AdapterClass`

```
private void free() {
        AlertClass alert=new AlertClass();
        alert.noInternetAlert(context);
           }
```

This is code for Adapter Class

```
public class BusyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BusyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private FragmentTransaction tx;
    private String myToken,name,join,description,id;
    private ArrayList<BusyEntry> entry;
    Context context;
    public BusyAdapter(ArrayList<BusyEntry> entry,Context context)
    {
        this.entry = entry;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.busy_card,parent,false);
         return  new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final BusyEntry currentEntry=entry.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(currentEntry.getName());
        holder.description.setText(currentEntry.getDescription());
        holder.id.setText(currentEntry.getId());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int pos=holder.getAdapterPosition();
                 name=entry.get(position).getName();
                 join=entry.get(position).getJoin();
                description=entry.get(position).getDescription();
                 id=entry.get(position).getId();
                final AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
                final AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
                builder.setMessage("Do you really want to Free?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        free();
                        String chooseTab="";
                        ChooseTab chooseTab1=new ChooseTab();
                        fm=activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                        Busy busy=new Busy();
                        tx=fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame,chooseTab1,chooseTab);
                        tx.detach(myentry);
                        tx.attach(myebtry);
                         entry.remove(pos);
                         notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                        tx.commit();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

How to show the Dialog in this method ?

Comment: try using context of the constructor. No Need to use                           
  final AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)v.getContext(); .  You have context already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the context in the adapter class. You need to use the context for creating alertDialog.

Remove this line first

```
final AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
```

And then use the context here.

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

Simply Use **v.getContext** change like this  `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext);`

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                        free();
                        String chooseTab="";
                        ChooseTab chooseTab1=new ChooseTab();
                        fm=activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                        Busy busy=new Busy();
                        tx=fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame,chooseTab1,chooseTab);
                        tx.detach(myentry);
                        tx.attach(myebtry);
                         entry.remove(pos);
                         notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                        tx.commit();
            }
        });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke NO event

            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Context` instead of `Activity` in `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
public void noInternetAlert(Activity activity)
{
    Context context = activity;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Not working.Still same error in Method while using Alert class

Comment: This is the way I am using                                                                                   private void free() {
        AlertClass alertClass=new AlertClass();
        alertClass.noInternetAlert(context);}                                                                                    This is error                                                             
    android.app.Activity cannot be applied to android.content.context

Comment: `final AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();` You need to change this to `final Context context = v.getContext();` in your adapter. Basically make sure you pass a context and not an activity to `AlertDialog.Builder`